# Connecting a function to a tab in Wt

Tags: c++, function, tabs, connect, wt

I am using the Wt library to write in C++ a website. I would like to use tabs on that website. To do so I use the `WTabWidget`.

In the documentation they make a tab and link each tab to a function :

```
Wt::WTabWidget *examples = new Wt::WTabWidget(this);
examples->addTab(helloWorldExample(), "Hello World");
examples->addTab(chartExample(), "Charts");
examples->addTab(new Wt::WText("A WText"), "WText");
```

Based on that I wrote this :
`WTabWidget *myTab = new WTabWidget();
 myTab->addTab(test(), "Test Tab");`

But my compiler tells me :

```
error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'Wt::WWidget *' with an rvalue of type 'void'
```

My "test" function has return type void. It's logic an rvalue of type void cannot be assigned to a parameter of type "WWidget*".

But if they show **that** example in the documentation, why can't I do it?

**that** : `examples->addTab(chartExample(), "Charts");`

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But if they show that example in the documentation, why can't I do it?

Their example function returns a widget, so you should do the same:

```
Wt::WWidget* test()
{
    Wt::WText *text = new Wt::WText("This is a test tab text");
    return text;
}
```